# Formula Fields Lock when Records are Locked?

Tags: approval-process, formula-field

Looking around the web I could not find any information on if a Formula field locks (data become static) on records that have been locked in an approval process when the values in the formula are updated on non locked related records.

I did a simple test and it seems that regardless of if a record is locked, the formula's stay dynamic based on  the related records current value.

Test Performed: 
Create an opportunity from an account and create a field on that opp that is of type formula, have it reference any field on the account. Lock the opportunity via an approval process. Change the related field on the account, the opportunity related field updates.

Is this suppose to happen? I was under the impression that a locked record is static?

Comment: AFAIK, this is expected.  I am looking for documentation to back this up, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Formula fields aren't actually stored in the database - this is what allows things like TODAY() functions and $User variables that are dynamic based on who and when it's accessed.

Technically speaking they're calculated on the fly when the record is queried. Because of this locking a record doesn't prevent them from having updated values. Likewise a formula field having a new value doesn't invoke workflow and triggers since no data changed; only the result of the stored formula did when recalculated.

Answer (score 3):

Formula fields are non-deterministic. That is, they are referential and the value of the formula field is exclusively derived from other fields and formula logic. Because of that, locking of formula fields is not possible.